# Problema con sockets y concurrencia en python (muchos clientes)

Tags: python, hilos, socket

estoy experimentando con python, la intención es hacer una estructura como la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que un cliente se comunica con el servidor central, este le envía un menú para preguntar sobre el horóscopo o el clima, el cliente le dice lo que quiere, el servidor central consulta a quien corresponda, la respuesta vuelve al servidor central y es este el que le da la respuesta al cliente (si no me equivoco, esto se diría que el servidor central actúa como proxy)

Hasta acá todo simple, esta idea me funciono excelente con un solo cliente, PERO mi problema fue cuando quise añadir concurrencia. Al momento de que hay muchos cliente, aunque lanze muchos hilos estos no terminan trabajando. Adjunto código comentado, no se si alguno me puede ayudar, estoy seguro que es de 1 a 10 líneas de código que hay que agregar para solucionar esto. Es la primera vez que trabajo con concurrencia en python (trabaje un montón con java) y con sockets en mi vida.

Lo que considero importante en el problema que esta en el cliente: creo que nada, porque para un solo cliente funciona bien, aunque uso hilos de la siguiente manera para probar con muchos clientes de la siguiente forma

```
import socket
from tcp import Tcp_interface
import time
import threading

HEADER=64
PORT=6050
SERVER = socket.gethostname() #could be also socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT="utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE="!DISCONNECT"

def send_client_request_predefined(ADDR, date, zodiacal_option):
   client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   client_socket.connect(ADDR)

   #We recive confirmation message
   introduction_mssg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
   print(introduction_mssg)

   #Comentado porque solo pasando esto ya genera problemas al momento de concurrencia
   #Un solo hilo anda biene
   '''
   input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)[3:]

   #We send the date
   print(input_msg+date)
   time.sleep(3)
   send_data=date
   Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)

   #We recive confirmation of correct format
   answer=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
   print(answer[3:])

   #We recive the menu option and send our option (Horosocpe in this case)
   input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
   print(input_msg[3:]+"2")
   time.sleep(3)
   Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("2",FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)

   #We recive the zodiacal sign option menu and we send an option
   send_data=str(zodiacal_option)
   input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
   print(input_msg[3:]+send_data)
   time.sleep(3)
   Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)

   #We recive the horoscope
   answer=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
   print(answer[3:])

   #We recive the main menu and ask the forecast
   input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
   send_data="1"
   print(input_msg[3:]+send_data)
   time.sleep(3)
   Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)

   #We recive the forecast
   answer=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
   print(answer[3:])

   #We recive the main menu and exit from the programa
   input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
   send_data="4"
   print(input_msg[3:]+send_data)
   time.sleep(3)
   Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)
   '''

   #We close connection
   client_socket.close()
   print("Closed connection. Bye!")
   pass

def clients_generator():
   dates=[ "01/08/94",
        "01/08/94",
        "07/02/94",
        "10/04/94",
        "07/03/94",
        "07/10/94",
        "07/02/94",
        "11/02/94",
        "07/08/94",
        "13/11/94"]
   zodiacal_options=[2,2,3,6,1,6,4,6,4,10]
   print(str(len(dates)))
   for i in range(0,3):

       addr=(SERVER,PORT+i)
       thread=threading.Thread(target=send_client_request_predefined, args=(addr,dates[i],zodiacal_options[i]))
       thread.start()
       pass
   pass

clients_generator()
```

El código del cliente en general:
import socket
from tcp import Tcp_interface
import time
import threading

```
HEADER=64
PORT=6050
SERVER = socket.gethostname() #could be also socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT="utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE="!DISCONNECT"


def send_client_request(socket):
    #We recive confirmation message
    introduction_mssg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    print(introduction_mssg)
    
    connected=True
    input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(socket,HEADER,FORMAT)[3:]

    while(connected):
        send_data=str(input(input_msg))
        Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,socket)
        if(send_data==DISCONNECT_MESSAGE or send_data=="4"):
            connected=False
        else:
            answer=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
            if(answer[0:3]=="[O]"):
                print(answer[3:])
                answer=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
                pass
            input_msg=answer[3:]
            pass
        pass
    socket.close()
    pass

def send_client_request_predefined(ADDR, date, zodiacal_option):
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect(ADDR)

    #We recive confirmation message
    introduction_mssg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    print(introduction_mssg)
    
    #Comentado porque solo pasando esto ya genera problemas al momento de concurrencia
    #Un solo hilo anda biene
    '''
    input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)[3:]

    #We send the date
    print(input_msg+date)
    time.sleep(3)
    send_data=date
    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)
    
    #We recive confirmation of correct format
    answer=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    print(answer[3:])
    
    #We recive the menu option and send our option (Horosocpe in this case)
    input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    print(input_msg[3:]+"2")
    time.sleep(3)
    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("2",FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)

    #We recive the zodiacal sign option menu and we send an option
    send_data=str(zodiacal_option)
    input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    print(input_msg[3:]+send_data)
    time.sleep(3)
    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)

    #
    #We recive the horoscope
    answer=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    print(answer[3:])

    #We recive the main menu and ask the forecast
    input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    send_data="1"
    print(input_msg[3:]+send_data)
    time.sleep(3)
    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)
    
    #We recive the forecast
    answer=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    print(answer[3:])


    #We recive the main menu and exit from the programa
    input_msg=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(client_socket,HEADER,FORMAT)
    send_data="4"
    print(input_msg[3:]+send_data)
    time.sleep(3)
    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(send_data,FORMAT,HEADER,client_socket)
    '''

    #We close connection
    client_socket.close()
    print("Closed connection. Bye!")
    pass

def clients_generator():
    
    dates=[ "01/08/94",
            "01/08/94",
            "07/02/94",
            "10/04/94",
            "07/03/94",
            "07/10/94",
            "07/02/94",
            "11/02/94",
            "07/08/94",
            "13/11/94"]
    zodiacal_options=[2,2,3,6,1,6,4,6,4,10]
    print(str(len(dates)))
    for i in range(0,3):

        addr=(SERVER,PORT+i)
        thread=threading.Thread(target=send_client_request_predefined, args=(addr,dates[i],zodiacal_options[i]))
        thread.start()
        pass
    pass


#client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#client.connect(ADDR)

#send_client_request_predefined(ADDR,"01/02/99","3")
#send_client_request(client)
#send_client_request_predefined(ADDR,"01/02/99","2")
clients_generator()
```

Lo que considero importante del problema del lado del servidor:

```
import socket 
import select
import threading #to run multiple threads in python
from tcp import Tcp_interface
from datetime import datetime

#Define port and server
PORT=6050
SERVER = socket.gethostname() #could be also socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT="utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE="!DISCONNECT"

#Define message's max size we will be allowed to recive
HEADER=64

INTRODUCTION_MSG="Hello! This server bring information about weather and horoscope based on a given date\n"
ASK_DATE_MSG= "Please send the date you want to know info (dd/mm/yy): "
ASK_OPTION_MSG="What do yo want to know?\n"+"   1 - Weather\n"+ "   2 - Horoscope\n"+"   3 - I want to know info about other date\n"+"   4 - I want to exit\n"+"Option selected: "
ERROR_MSG="INVALID OPTION ERROR. Please, choose a valid option"
ERROR_DATE_FORMAT="INVALID DATE FORMAT. Remeber the format is dd/mm/yy"

def handle_client(conn,addr):
    date=None
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] ({addr},{conn}) connected.")
    connected=True

    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(INTRODUCTION_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
    print(f"[ME] INTRODUCTION_MSG sent")
    '''
    date=ask_date(conn,addr)
    while connected:
        Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[I]"+ASK_OPTION_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
        msg_rcv=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(conn, HEADER,FORMAT)
        print(f"[{addr}] Option selected {msg_rcv}")
        if msg_rcv=="1":
            forecast=handle_weather_request(conn, addr,date)
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+forecast,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            pass
        elif msg_rcv=="2":
            horscope=handle_horscope_request(conn, addr,date)
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+horscope,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            pass
        elif msg_rcv=="3":
            date=ask_date(conn,addr)
            pass
        elif msg_rcv=="4":
            connected=False
            pass
        else:
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+ERROR_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            pass
        pass
    '''
    conn.close()
    print(f"[CLOSED CLIENT CONNECTION] ({addr},{conn}) connection closed")
    pass

def start():
    #We allow the server to listen requests from different conections
    server.listen(10) #10 connection limit, if you change this number you can add more, but they will require more resources
    print(f"[listening] Server is listening on {SERVER}")

    while True:
        #To wait a new connection, we store the tuple addr=(client's server,clients's port)
        #conn is a socket to communicate with the client
        conn,addr=server.accept()
        server.setblocking(1)
        thread=threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()-1}")
        pass
    pass


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
server.bind(ADDR) #we bind socket to an address, everyone who conect to the address will access to this socket
print("MAIN SERVER")
print("[STARTING] Server is starting")
start()
```

Código completo del servidor central:

```
import socket 
import select
import threading #to run multiple threads in python
from tcp import Tcp_interface
from datetime import datetime

#Define port and server
PORT=6050
SERVER = socket.gethostname() #could be also socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT="utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE="!DISCONNECT"

#Define message's max size we will be allowed to recive
HEADER=64

CLIMATE_SERVER=socket.gethostname()
CLIMATE_PORT=6052
ADR_WEATHER=(CLIMATE_SERVER,CLIMATE_PORT)

HOROSCOPE_SERVER=socket.gethostname()
HOROSCOPE_PORT=6051
ADR_HOROSCOPE=(HOROSCOPE_SERVER,HOROSCOPE_PORT)


INTRODUCTION_MSG="Hello! This server bring information about weather and horoscope based on a given date\n"
ASK_DATE_MSG= "Please send the date you want to know info (dd/mm/yy): "
ASK_OPTION_MSG="What do yo want to know?\n"+"   1 - Weather\n"+ "   2 - Horoscope\n"+"   3 - I want to know info about other date\n"+"   4 - I want to exit\n"+"Option selected: "
ERROR_MSG="INVALID OPTION ERROR. Please, choose a valid option"
ERROR_DATE_FORMAT="INVALID DATE FORMAT. Remeber the format is dd/mm/yy"

#We create a socket
#AF_INET is just a type of socket
#SOCK_STREAM for TCP, SOCKET_DRAGM for UDP
#https://zetcode.com/python/socket/#:~:text=The%20recv()%20method%20receives,returns%20an%20empty%20byte%20string.


def handle_horscope_request(conn,addr, date):
    #Ask zodiacal sign
    horoscope=""
    zodiacal_sign=ask_horoscope_zodiacal_sign(conn,addr)
    if(zodiacal_sign!=13):
        if(zodiacal_sign<10):
            zodiacal_sign="0"+str(zodiacal_sign)
            pass

        msg=date+" "+zodiacal_sign
        #Comunicate with horoscope server
        socket_horoscope=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket_horoscope.connect(ADR_HOROSCOPE)
        encoded_msg=msg.encode(FORMAT)
    
        socket_horoscope.send(encoded_msg)
        horoscope=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(socket_horoscope,HEADER,FORMAT)
        socket_horoscope.close()
        print("[CLOSED HOROSCOPE SERVER CONNECTION]")
        pass
    return horoscope

def handle_weather_request(conn,addr, date):
    #Comunicate with weather server
    socket_weather=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_weather.connect(ADR_WEATHER)
    print("Date: " + str(date))
    encoded_date=date.encode(FORMAT)
    #print(str(len(encoded_date)))
    socket_weather.send(encoded_date)
    forecast=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(socket_weather,HEADER,FORMAT)
    socket_weather.close()
    print("[CLOSED CLIMATE SERVER CONNECTION]")
    return forecast

HOROSCOPE_ASK_MSG="Which is your zodiacal sign?\n"+"   1 - Aries (21/03 - 20/04)\n"+"   2 - Taurus (21/04 - 21/05)\n"+"   3 - Gemini (22/05 - 21/06)\n"+"   4 - Cancer (22/06 - 22/07)\n"+"   5 - Leo (23/07 - 22/08)\n"+"   6 - Virgo (23/08 - 22/09)\n"+"   7 - Libra (23/09 - 22/10)\n"+"   8 - Scorpio (23/10 - 21/11)\n"+"   9 - Sagittarius (22/11 - 21/12)\n"+"   10 - Capricorn (22/12 - 20/01)\n"+"   11 - Aquarius (21/01 - 19/02)\n"+"   12 - Pisces (20/02 - 20/03)\n"+"   13 - Return to previous menu\n"+"Option selected: "
HOROSCOPE_ERROR_MSG="ERROR INVALID VALUE. Input a value greater than 0 and lower than 14"

def ask_horoscope_zodiacal_sign(conn,addr):
    zodiacal_sign_option=-1
    ask_again=True

    while (ask_again):
        Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[I]"+HOROSCOPE_ASK_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
        try:
            zodiacal_sign_option=int(Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(conn,HEADER,FORMAT))
            if(zodiacal_sign_option<0 or zodiacal_sign_option>13):
                Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+HOROSCOPE_ERROR_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            else:
                ask_again=False
            pass
        except ValueError:
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+HOROSCOPE_ERROR_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            pass
        pass
    return zodiacal_sign_option

def ask_date(conn,addr):
    date=None
    ask_again=True

    while(ask_again):
        try:
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[I]"+ASK_DATE_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            date=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(conn, HEADER,FORMAT)
            date=datetime.strptime(date,'%d/%m/%y') #To verify correct format
            print(f"[{addr}{conn}] GIVEN DATE {date.date()}")
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+"CORRECT FROMAT",FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            ask_again=False
        except ValueError:
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+ERROR_DATE_FORMAT,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            pass
        pass
    return str(date.date())

def handle_client(conn,addr):
    date=None
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] ({addr},{conn}) connected.")
    connected=True

    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(INTRODUCTION_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
    print(f"[ME] INTRODUCTION_MSG sent")
    '''
    date=ask_date(conn,addr)
    while connected:
        Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[I]"+ASK_OPTION_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
        msg_rcv=Tcp_interface.recive_TCP_messg(conn, HEADER,FORMAT)
        print(f"[{addr}] Option selected {msg_rcv}")
        if msg_rcv=="1":
            forecast=handle_weather_request(conn, addr,date)
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+forecast,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            pass
        elif msg_rcv=="2":
            horscope=handle_horscope_request(conn, addr,date)
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+horscope,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            pass
        elif msg_rcv=="3":
            date=ask_date(conn,addr)
            pass
        elif msg_rcv=="4":
            connected=False
            pass
        else:
            Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg("[O]"+ERROR_MSG,FORMAT,HEADER,conn)
            pass
        pass
    '''
    conn.close()
    print(f"[CLOSED CLIENT CONNECTION] ({addr},{conn}) connection closed")
    pass

def start():
    #We allow the server to listen requests from different conections
    server.listen(10) #10 connection limit, if you change this number you can add more, but they will require more resources
    print(f"[listening] Server is listening on {SERVER}")

    while True:
        #To wait a new connection, we store the tuple addr=(client's server,clients's port)
        #conn is a socket to communicate with the client
        conn,addr=server.accept()
        server.setblocking(1)
        thread=threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()-1}")
        pass
    pass


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
server.bind(ADDR) #we bind socket to an address, everyone who conect to the address will access to this socket
print("MAIN SERVER")
print("[STARTING] Server is starting")
start()
```

Código completo servidor horóscopo:
import socket
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from tcp import Tcp_interface

```
#Define port and server
PORT=6051
SERVER = socket.gethostname() #could be also socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT="utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE="!DISCONNECT"

#Define message's max size we will be allowed to recive
HEADER=64

HOROSCOPE_MESSAGES=[ "You'll have a great day",
                    "You'll have a bad day",
                    "Your salary'll be the same, but your expenses'll increase",
                    "Please! Get out of this country", 
                    "You won't commit suicide", 
                    "You'll be MendoExit's leader",
                    "She doesn't love you",
                    "You may commit suicide",
                    "Netflix is a good plan, because nobody loves you, and you're ugly",
                    "You'll open up with somebody you love, only to realize that this person probably has a metal illness and can't be racional",
                    "You won't cross the bridge",
                    "If you live in Argentina you should buy a gun",
                    "The one who bet on dollar lose",
                    "Catch yourself Catherine",
                    "You'll move aboard",
                    "A new job is at the corner",
                    "A friend'll betray you",
                    "You'll betray a friend",
                    "Watch mr robot",
                    "Watch Game of thrones",
                    "Watch Breaking Bad",
                    "Hang out with a friend, this may save your life",
                    "All the pain you feel today'll be less in the future, I hope",
                    "Buy cake",
                    "Hold TRON and DENT",
                    "Give them a good reason to know you are tough",
                    "Please choose to live",
                    "You're a good guy, you'll be a better father"                       
                    ]

ZODIACAL_DICTIONARY={1: "Aries", 2: "Taurus", 3: "Gemini", 4: "Cancer", 5: "Leo", 6: "Virgo", 7:"Libra", 8: "Scorpio", 9: "Sagittarius", 10: "Capricorn",  11: "Aquarius", 12: "Pisces"}

def handle_request(conn,addr):
    #We recive date and zodiacal sign code
    
    date_zodiacal_code=conn.recv(13).decode(FORMAT)
    date_zodiacal_code=date_zodiacal_code.split()

    date=datetime.strptime(date_zodiacal_code[0],'%Y-%m-%d')
    zodiacal_sign_number=int(date_zodiacal_code[1])

    code_horoscope_message=(date.year+date.month+date.day+ zodiacal_sign_number) %len(HOROSCOPE_MESSAGES)
    message=ZODIACAL_DICTIONARY[zodiacal_sign_number]+f"({date.day}/{date.month}/{date.year}): "+ HOROSCOPE_MESSAGES[code_horoscope_message]
    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(message,FORMAT, HEADER,conn)
    
    conn.close()
    print(f"[CONNECTION CLOSED] {addr}: {conn}")   
    pass

def start():
    #We allow the server to listen requests from different conections
    server.listen(10)
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")

    while True:
        #To wait a new connection, we store the tuple addr=(client's server,clients's port)
        #conn is a socket to communicate with the client
        conn,addr=server.accept()
        thread=threading.Thread(target=handle_request, args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()-1}")
        pass
    pass


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR) #we bind socket to an address, everyone who conect to the address will access to this socket
print("HOROSCOPE SERVER")
print("[STARTING] Server is starting")
start()
```

Código completo del servidor clima:

```
import socket
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from tcp import Tcp_interface

#Define port and server
PORT=6052
SERVER = socket.gethostname() #could be also socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT="utf-8"


#Define message's max size we will be allowed to recive
HEADER=64
FORECAST=["Cloudy", "Foggy", "Icy", "Rainy", "Snowy", "Stormy", "Sunny", "Thundery","Windy", "Hot", "Warm", "Cool", "Cold", "Freezing"]

def handle_request(conn,addr):
    date=conn.recv(10).decode(FORMAT)
    date=datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d')

    code_forecast_message=(date.year+date.month+date.day) %len(FORECAST)
    message=FORECAST[code_forecast_message]
    
    Tcp_interface.send_TCP_messg(message,FORMAT, HEADER,conn)
    
    conn.close()
    print(f"[CONNECTION CLOSED] {addr}: {conn}")
    pass

def start():
    #We allow the server to listen requests from different conections
    server.listen(10)
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")

    while True:
        #To wait a new connection, we store the tuple addr=(client's server,clients's port)
        #conn is a socket to communicate with the client
        conn,addr=server.accept()
        thread=threading.Thread(target=handle_request, args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()-1}")
        pass
    pass


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #Genera socket con valores por default
server.bind(ADDR) #host y puerto

print("CLIMATE SERVER")
print("[STARTING] Server is starting")
start()
```

Código completo TCP (clase utilizada habitualmente en todas las clases anteriores):

```
class Tcp_interface:

    @staticmethod
    def send_TCP_messg(text, format, header_size, socket):
        encoded_text=text.encode(format)

        encoded_text_len=str(len(encoded_text)).encode(format) #First we sent the len the server should reead
        encoded_text_len+=b' '* (header_size-len(encoded_text_len))
        socket.send(encoded_text_len)

        #We sent the message
        socket.send(encoded_text)
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def recive_TCP_messg(socket,header,format):
        text_len= int(socket.recv(header).decode(format))
        return socket.recv(text_len).decode(format)

    pass
```

Nota: al momento de ejecutar que todo este en una misma carpeta. Si ejecutan solo la parte relevante del servidor y el cliente, primero el servidor y después el cliente.

Donde puede estar el problema es en los metodos start y handle_client de servidor y en send_client_request_predefined y clients_generator de cliente.

Comment: Separe el codigo en la parte qye YO considero relevante y la parte que no, lo deje claro en la publicaicón, pero deje el resto por si alguno quiere ojear más

Comment: Tienes un problema de arquitectura. Cuando tratamos con servicios web, tenemos el wsgi o asgi que enlaza peticiones http a codigo python.  Creo en tu caso que solo tienes un hilo, pues solo puedes atender a uno a la vez.  No tengo nidea exactamente como multiplexar los sockets directos, pero si estoy seguro que si le pones un loop async de python ( y conviertes tus funcioens en async ready), podras atenter a infinitas peticiones

Comment: puedes empezar por ahi: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html   https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams